# Cordova App showing code not rendered page

Tags: php, jquery, cordova

I've changed `<content src="index.html" />` to `<content src="index.php" />` and all I am getting is the app showing the entire source code and not the rendered jQuery page. Why is this happening?

Comment: Addl info from @Matthew: It works on the live site, but it won't show the pages when the code is built with cordova into an app. I'm not sure if there is another setting I need to change or something? PHP works on the web server just fine but cordova is not parsing the code its just displaying it raw.

Comment: Cordova doesn't support PHP. It only supports HTML, CSS and Javascript. Ionic and ng-cordova supports angularJS additionally.

Answer (score 0):

> Apache Cordova is an open-source mobile development framework. It allows you to use **standard web technologies** - HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript for cross-platform development. Applications execute within wrappers targeted to each platform, and rely on standards-compliant API bindings to access each device's capabilities such as sensors, data, network status, etc.

It does not have a server to interpret PHP code. You can make use of AJAX calls to communicate to the server where you can handle your PHP code and process the result in client side with available APIs in Cordova.

Comment: So I eliminated the PHP code from the page, and it still is showing only the code and not parsing the page...i left only the essential HTML, CSS, and JS/jQuery and it still won't parse. What am I missing?

Comment: @Matthew could you post your index.HTML, config.XML and project structure please?